# xslt replace function

Tags: .net, xslt

I am using `fn:replace(string,pattern,replace)` function to replace `','` to `'.'`. URI i used for the function is http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions. But i m getting an exception saying

> System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException: Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'fn'

Can anybody tell me what is the issue.

Thanks in advance
Pradeep

Answer (score 4):

You can use this instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(string, ',', '.')" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The .net framework implements XSLT 1.0 only, and the new functions such as replace are in the XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 Functions and Operators spec which is not supported.

You will have to make do with [translate](https://web.archive.org/web/20150726005503/http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) or a hack such as [described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx).

Comment: If you want to use XSLT and XPath 2.0 with the Microsoft .NET framework then you can consider using the .NET version of Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/.